# An error occurs when using ezdxf to describe the layer property description

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocad, dxf, ezdxf

An error occurs when using ezdxf to describe the layer property description.
There are layer names that cause errors and layer names that do not. I do not know the cause.

I tried using the code below.

```py
lay = dwg.layers.get('MyLayerHere')
app = 'AcAecLayerStandard'
dsc = 'MyDescriptionHere'

if lay.tags.has_xdata(app):
    lay.tags.set_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
else:
    dwg.appids.new(app)
    lay.tags.new_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
```

error contents

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "file.py", line 777, in dwg.appids.new(app) File "C:\・・・\table.py", line 63, in new raise DXFTableEntryError('%s %s already exists!' % (self._dxfname, name)) ezdxf.lldxf.const.DXFTableEntryError: APPID AcAecLayerStandard already exists!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error will arise in your code when attempting to assign a description to a layer *without* an existing description, but within a drawing containing other layers *with* a description (i.e. within a drawing in which the `AcAecLayerStandard` Application ID is already registered).

To avoid this, simply test whether the `AcAecLayerStandard` Application ID is already registered before adding it to the `APPID` symbol table, e.g.:

```
lay = dwg.layers.get('MyLayerHere')
app = 'AcAecLayerStandard'
dsc = 'MyDescriptionHere'

if lay.tags.has_xdata(app):
    lay.tags.set_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
else:
    if app not in dwg.appids:
        dwg.appids.new(app)
    lay.tags.new_xdata(app, [(1000, ''), (1000, dsc)])
```